# How to use BouncyCastle lightwigth API to generate cms enveloped data

Tags: java, bouncycastle, pkcs#1

After struggling uncountable hours I finally have the current working code to generate CMS enveloped (RSA-OAEP / PKCS#1) data with recipient info using JCE/JCA:

```
String digest = "SHA-256";
String mgfDigest = "SHA-256";

// Data to encrypt
CMSTypedData msg = new CMSProcessableByteArray(data);

// Generator for my CMS enveloped data 
CMSEnvelopedDataGenerator envelopedDataGen = new CMSEnvelopedDataGenerator();

// Recipient Info Stuff
JcaAlgorithmParametersConverter paramsConverter = new JcaAlgorithmParametersConverter();
OAEPParameterSpec oaepSpec = new OAEPParameterSpec(digest, "MGF1", new MGF1ParameterSpec(mgfDigest), PSource.PSpecified.DEFAULT);
AlgorithmIdentifier oaepAlgId = paramsConverter.getAlgorithmIdentifier(PKCSObjectIdentifiers.id_RSAES_OAEP, oaepSpec);
envelopedDataGen.addRecipientInfoGenerator(
        new JceKeyTransRecipientInfoGenerator(
                getCert(), 
                oaepAlgId).setProvider("BC"));

/*
  * Generate CMS-Data
  * CMSOutputEncryptor is my own Class implementing OutputEncryptor
  */
CMSEnvelopedData ed = envelopedDataGen.generate(
        msg, 
        new CMSOutputEncryptor());

byte[] encoded = ed.getEncoded();
```

This works as expected but because it uses JCE my customers need to install the unlimited strength api to use this code. I would prefer a way to overcome these needs because most of my customers fingers are thumbs...

Maybe someone can show me a piece of code which use a pure BouncyCastle way of doing the same so that one don't need to install the unlimited strength api?

Answer (score 0):

*Please note that I am not sure if this is legal in all countries / for all customers.*

If you want to remove the restriction, you can work with some reflection magic. This is how I do it in my framework (Partially taken from: https://github.com/jruby/jruby/blob/0c345e1b186bd457ebd96143c0816abe93b18fdf/core/src/main/java/org/jruby/util/SecurityHelper.java):

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.Modifier;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;

public class UnlimitedStrengthHelper {

    public static void removeCryptoStrengthRestriction() {
        try {
            if (Cipher.getMaxAllowedKeyLength("AES") < 256) {
                Class jceSecurity = Class.forName("javax.crypto.JceSecurity");
                Field isRestricted = jceSecurity.getDeclaredField("isRestricted");
                if (Modifier.isFinal(isRestricted.getModifiers())) {
                    Field modifiers = Field.class.getDeclaredField("modifiers");
                    modifiers.setAccessible(true);
                    modifiers.setInt(isRestricted, isRestricted.getModifiers() & ~Modifier.FINAL);
                    modifiers.setAccessible(false);
                }
                isRestricted.setAccessible(true);
                isRestricted.setBoolean(null, false);
                isRestricted.setAccessible(false);
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException
                | NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchFieldException | SecurityException ex) {
            System.out.println("It is not possible to use unrestricted policy with this JDK, "
                    + "consider reconfiguration: " + ex.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

The code first checks whether the restriction exists (in that case, you cannot work with AES256). Afterwards, it takes the *JceSecurity* class and its *isRestricted* field. It ensures that we can access this field and finally sets its value to false.

Btw., thank you for your CMS example, it helped me a lot.

Comment: Thanks for this code but AFAIK this won't work anymore because the static fields are finally now. Please have a look at https://github.com/jruby/jruby/issues/4101. In the end I decided to deliver a full java jre with unlimited strength api enabled. But good to know that my piece of code was a help for you.

Comment: This line sets the modifier to non-final:

modifiers.setInt(isRestricted, isRestricted.getModifiers() & ~Modifier.FINAL);